# ethers.js GetAmountsOut returns [object Promise]

Tags: ethers.js

I am trying to get the amount out of a token using node.js.

I have imported ethers and run the following code.

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const addresses = {
  router: '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E',
}

const router = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.router,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
  ],
);

tokenIn = '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c'; 
tokenOut = '0x126f5f2a88451d24544f79d11f869116351d46e1';

const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', 'ether');
const amountsOut = router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenIn, tokenOut]);
  console.log(`
    tokenOut: ${amountsOut.toString()}
`);
```

I get the following error

```
tokenOut: [object Promise]
(node:8556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null
```

Im guessing its either something to do with trying to call outside of an async function. How can I use getAmountsOut to get an estimate of tokens returned before swapping? thanks

Comment: Add await before router ?

Comment: You should have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @MajdTL syntax error: await is only valid in async function.

Comment: How are u running the script? It is a JavaScript problem , u can try to use (.then) or warp that inside an asynch function , take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227550/using-await-inside-non-async-function

Comment: Hi @MajdTL. Just running through node.js on run execute script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is still unanswered, you can do the following:

```
// ... previous code
const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseUnits('0.1', 'ether');

// put the asynchronous stuff and it's dependent code inside an IIFE
(async() => {
  const amountsOut = router.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenIn, tokenOut]);
  console.log(`
    tokenOut: ${amountsOut.toString()}
`);
})();
```